# BroadcastReceiver in Android N 7.0

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

I want to send broadcast message and catch it in `BroadcastReceiver`.

This is how I send a message:

```
  override fun addToSchedule(event: EntityObject) {
    val pendingIntent = createEventPushPendingIntent(event)
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, computeTimeToPush(event), pendingIntent)
}

  private fun createEventPushPendingIntent(event: EntityObject): PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(ctx, EventScheduleBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
      .putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_INFO, EventInfo(event))
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, event.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
  }
```

In this case I use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` but actually I tried all flags and 0.

This is how I catch message:

```
class EventScheduleBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

  private val lifeCycleManager = DCLifecycleManager.getInstance()

  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val serializableEventInfo: Serializable? = intent.getSerializableExtra(EventInfo.EXTRA_EVENT_INFO)
    if (serializableEventInfo is EventInfo) {
      lifeCycleManager.pushProcessor.pushEventSchedule(context, serializableEventInfo)
    }
  }
}
```

My broadcastreceiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="ru.campuz.feature.schedule.EventScheduleBroadcastReceiver" />
```

My problem is: on the Android 7.0 in method `onReceive` I always get empty extras in `intent`. But on all other versions below I get `intent` with extras. I always want to get `intent` with extras.

What must I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue for check internet connection in whole of app ,based on [android document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes)

Context.registerReceiver() is still valid.
so i have register a LocalBroadcastReceiver in class that extend Application class

```
 private fun registerNetReceiver() {
        val bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(G.NET_DISCONNECT)
        bManager.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    //call when in factor page we go back and want to apply food count change in foods item in Product adapter
    private val mMessageReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == G.NET_DISCONNECT){
                val actType = intent.getIntExtra("ACT_TYPE",0)
                val i = Intent(MyApplication.instance(),NetDisActivity::class.java)
                i.putExtra("ACT_TYPE",actType)
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

and in whole activity check network connection with this method

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
        }
```

and if top method return false then call broadcast like bellow

```
val intent = Intent(G.NET_DISCONNECT)
    intent.putExtra("ACT_TYPE",actType) //even can pass data
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```